# hql select from final table

Tags: hibernate, hql, final, dbvisualizer

Here is my query:

```
update JSNumber set runningNo=(select runningNo +1 from JSNumber where paymentDate= '2015-07-09 00:00:00.0' ) where paymentDate = '2015-07-09 00:00:00.0'
```

This is working fine when I set it to a `StringBuilder` sb, and run as follow:

```
Query query = getSession( ).createQuery( sb.toString( ) );
```

Here is my edited query:

```
select runningNo from final table (update JSNumber set runningNo=(select runningNo +1 from JSNumber where paymentDate= '2015-07-09 00:00:00.0' ) where paymentDate = '2015-07-09 00:00:00.0' )
```

I add in `select runningNo from final table ()` in front of the original query.
This is working fine when I run it in `DBVisualizer`, but when I want to run as hql, I hit

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 35
```

Kindly advise how to write it in hql query.

Answer (score 0):

Just found something. Use `createSqlQuery()` instead of `createQuery()` can solve this problem.